# Execute two commands under condition in for loop in makefile

Tags: bash, makefile

Code in my MakeFile:

```
for i in $(SUBDIRS); do \
($(MAKE) -C $$i) || (exit $$? && rm -rf bin);  \
done
```

If an error in submakes occurs I need to delete the `bin` directory. How to execute it together, i.e. how to launch `exit $$?` and `rm -rf bin` simultaneously? Now only `exit $$?` is executed.

Comment: Makefile syntax is not bash syntax. It's used to *generate* code parsed as bash syntax, sure, but someone who knows only bash and not make will not be able to usefully contribute to this question.

Comment: ...and btw, are you setting `SHELL=/bin/bash` elsewhere in your makefile? (If not, this is a question about `sh` -- the default shell used by make -- not bash).

Comment: ...backing up, and speaking to the code you're generating, note that `exit` *stops execution*. It's thus the last thing a shell (or subshell) ever executes by definition, so "exit, then *do this other thing*" makes no sense. Similarly, "exit and do this other thing simultaneously" doesn't really make any sense either -- to do two things simultaneously, you need to split into two processes, so if you *did* fork off a subshell to do the exit, it would be a separate process than the one running "rm", and wouldn't have any effect on the latter's exit status.

Comment: If to change `exit` and `remove` places then what syntaxis to use?

Comment: In bash, with no `make` involved, you might want `make -C "$i" || { retval=$?; rm -rf bin; exit "$retval"; }`. I haven't written nontrivial makefiles professionally for 15 years now, so I'm the wrong person to describe how to change that from bash to make syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Save the return code before you call either rm or exit.
2. Running exit inside a `()` will not exit, because it is running in a subshell. Use `{}`. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html (This page is for bash, but sh is the same in this way.)

Example:

```
SUBDIRS := $(wildcard */.)

all:
    @for i in $(SUBDIRS); do \
        $(MAKE) -C $$i || { RETVAL=$$?; rm -rf bin; exit $$RETVAL; }; \
    done
```

Comment: There's no need to run `make` in a separate subhell, either.

Comment: @tripleee Thanks, fixed.